# Why ActualWidth and ActualHeight start from 0,0?

Tags: wpf, selection, inkcanvas, actualwidth, actualheight

I want to add WPF Path to `InkCanvas` and use selection to select WPF Path. 
So, I use this code.

```
System.Windows.Shapes.Path path = drawCanvas.Children[i] as System.Windows.Shapes.Path;    
drawCanvas.Children.RemoveAt(i);
inkCanvas.Children.Add(path);
```

This is the output. I have to select WPF Path from 0,0 because `Actualwidth` and `ActualHeight` start from 0,0.

[image]

How do I select absolute WPF Path?

Thanks

**Edit:**

Now, I can select it absolutely by using this code.

```
System.Windows.Shapes.Path path = drawCanvas.Children[i] as System.Windows.Shapes.Path;
drawCanvas.Children.RemoveAt(i);
path.Margin = new Thickness(-getMinX(path), -getMinY(path), 0, 0);
containPath.Children.Add(path);
containPath.Width = getMaxX(path) - getMinX(path);
containPath.Height = getMaxY(path) - getMinY(path);
containPath.Margin = new Thickness(getMinX(path), getMinY(path), 0, 0);
inkCanvas.Children.Add(containPath);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [UIElement.UpdateLayout Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.updatelayout.aspx) on the `InkCanvas` to update the [FrameworkElement.ActualWidth Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.actualwidth(VS.96).aspx) and `ActualHeight`.  See the `ActualWidth` link for background information on why this is needed.

**Edit:**

I misunderstood the question.  It wasn't that `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` were zero but that their values were relative to `(0, 0)` on the `InkCanvas`.  A pretty good solution to the problem is to wrap the `Path` in a `Canvas` and position it using `Margin` like this:

```
<Canvas Width="50" Height="50" Margin="200,200,0,0">
    <Line
        X1="0" Y1="0"
        X2="50" Y2="50"
        Stroke="Black"
        StrokeThickness="4" />
</Canvas>
```

which behaves like:

[image]

The disadvantage of this approach is the user has to lasso the `Canvas` which is a rectangle, not an arbitrary shape.  Nevertheless, it's a lot better than having to lasso the object **and** the origin.

Comment: I dont think UpdateLayout will do anything.

Comment: We don't have enough code to test the theory but if `UIElement.IsMeasureValid` is `false`, there is no hope of `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` being correct.

Comment: Please see my answer. In my earlier comment I meant to say that UpdateLayout will not do anything for a 'Path'

Comment: Thanks, I can select it absolutely now.

Comment: +1 - Thanks @RickSladkey, using UpdateLayout() based on your answer made ActualWidth become available in my project.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For elements that can only be defined via control points (eg Line, Path etc as against Rectangle, Ellipse etc) when you add it to an items control (which I assume the `InkCanvas` is since it supports selection), first a canvas is added to the panel at 0,0. The width and the `Height` of the canvas are determined from the maximum X and Y coordinates of the control points. After this the element is added as a child of this canvas.

You will also see that whenever you see this kind of behaviors with an element, the element wont support Layout Properties like Horizontal/Vertical alignment etc.

The only way I see around this is to find the `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` manually from the coordinates in the path.

**Edit:** This is from personal experience and not from any documentation.

Comment: I can find ActualWidth and ActualHeight manually now. But I cannot set them to ActualWidth and ActualHeight because they are read only.

Comment: ActualWidth and ActualHeight are readonly dependency properties (if memory serves right). You simply cannot and should not set it yourself.

Comment: For selection adorners, you will have to do a lot of manual stuff to do what you want. When you add an item to an inkcanvas it will be wrapped into a container item. This container item is what is decorated by the selection adorner. Since you container contains the canvas starting at 0,0, you see the odd selection box. You need to create a derived container item which takes care of selection adorners yourself.

Comment: Frankly, if you have just started out with WPF, this is going to look like a huge task because you will need to do a lot of sub classing and come up with your own derived InkCanvas and children etc. And the final result doesnt show much for it. :D

Comment: The InkCanvas has two selection concepts: elements and strokes.  The elements have all the problems you describe.  But what if we convert the path, which appears to be a series of line segments, into strokes?  Then we can let the InkCanvas do its job with the lasso.

Comment: What you suggest is possible. Problem is except for delete, the adorner is pretty much useless in this case. Even for moving(as against resizing) you will need a custom element. My experience had been that subclassing is the only logical solution to what I believe OP wants to do after selection.